# asp.net core model changes not shown in frontend (razor)

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

i have started a new asp.net core application and I am able to get the values to be displayed from the model - but only the ones that are put onto the properties at the beginning of the file.

If I change them at runtime, the changes are not displayed - with my debugger however I can see that the model value is actually changes to the correct value.
It has probably something to do with the way this are done  - or in what order.

Here is my start:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

    public string telephone { get; set; } = "empty";
    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        LoadData();
    }

    private async void LoadData()
    {
        var userService = new RemoteUserService();
        var test = await userService.GetItemByEmail("asd@asd.de");
        if (test != null)
        {
            telephone = test[0].Telephone;
        }
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
}
```

and codebehind:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
    <p>@Model.telephone</p>
</div>
```

Again, the properties are found correctly, its just the data doesnt change once the `RemoteUserService` has downloaded the value.

EDIT:
An issue seems to be that the call for load data is not awaited...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that I didnt AWAIT the result. This here will work:

```
    private async Task LoadData(string email)
    {
        var userService = new RemoteUserService();
        var test = await userService.GetItemByEmail(email);

        if (test != null)
        {
            telephone = test[0].Telephone;
        }

    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
    {
        await LoadData("asd@asd.de");
        return Page();
    }
```